# How to fix vertical spacing of inputs with css and flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, and I'm coding it straight from html, css, and javascript. I have one section where I have a button in a div, a text input in a div, and another button in a div stacked on top of each other. For some reason the text input has significantly less space between it and the top button, and more space between it and the bottom button.

I was going to create a simple example so I don't have to post all my code here, but I wasn't able to replicate it outside of my project. I've tried viewing it in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge, same problem in all of them. I've messed with the dimensions of the containing div, and tried several different css keywords without luck.

Here's my index.html:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DnDnBeyond</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ch_sheet">
                <div class="ch_header">
                    <div class="ch_info_wrapper">
                        <div class="ch_info">
                            <div class="ch_info_name" id="name">Gilan</div>
                            <div class="ch_info_secondary">
                                <span class="ch_info_label" id="race">Half Elf</span>
                                <span class="ch_info_label" id="class">Ranger</span>
                                <span class="ch_info_label" id="level">4</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ch_stats">

                        <!--STR-->
                        <div class="ch_stat">
                            <div class="ch_stat_header">Strength</div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_primary">
                                <span id="str_primary" class="ch_stat_primary_label">+1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_secondary" id="str_secondary">12</div>
                        </div>

                        <!--DEX-->
                        <div class="ch_stat">
                            <div class="ch_stat_header">Dexterity</div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_primary">
                                <span id="dex_primary" class="ch_stat_primary_label">+3</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_secondary" id="dex_secondary">16</div>
                        </div>

                        <!--CON-->
                        <div class="ch_stat">
                            <div class="ch_stat_header">Constitution</div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_primary">
                                <span id="con_primary" class="ch_stat_primary_label">+3</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_secondary" id="con_secondary">16</div>
                        </div>

                        <!--INT-->
                        <div class="ch_stat">
                            <div class="ch_stat_header">Intelligence</div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_primary">
                                <span id="int_primary" class="ch_stat_primary_label">+3</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_secondary" id="int_secondary">16</div>
                        </div>

                        <!--WIS-->
                        <div class="ch_stat">
                            <div class="ch_stat_header">Wisdom</div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_primary">
                                <span id="wis_primary" class="ch_stat_primary_label">+1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_secondary" id="wis_secondary">12</div>
                        </div>

                        <!--CHA-->
                        <div class="ch_stat">
                            <div class="ch_stat_header">Charisma</div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_primary">
                                <span id="cha_primary" class="ch_stat_primary_label">+1</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_stat_secondary" id="cha_secondary">12</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ch_health_wrapper">
                        <div class="ch_health">
                            <div class="ch_health_label_wrapper">
                                <span class="ch_health_label" id="health_label">Hit Points</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_hp">
                                <div class="ch_hp_adjuster">
                                    <div class="ch_hp_adjuster_button">
                                        <button class="ch_hp_heal_button" id="heal_button">Heal</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ch_hp_adjuster_input_wrapper">
                                        <input type="number" class="ch_hp_adjuster_input"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ch_hp_adjuster_button">
                                        <button class="ch_hp_damage_button" id="damage_button">Damage</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ch_hp_current">
                                    <div class="ch_hp_label">Current</div>
                                    <span class="ch_hp_number" id="current_hp">36</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ch_hp_sep">/</div>
                                <div class="ch_hp_max">
                                    <div class="ch_hp_label">Max</div>
                                    <span class="ch_hp_number" id="max_hp">44</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ch_death_saves"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The section is around lines 86-96, the containing div has the class ch_hp_adjuster.

Here are the relevant css classes:

```css
.ch_health_wrapper {
    flex: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ch_health {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 2px solid #B89A67;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.ch_health_label {
    padding: 4px 4px 6px 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed,Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ch_hp {
    display: flex;
}

.ch_hp_adjuster {
    flex: 30%;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.ch_hp_adjuster_button {
}

.ch_hp_heal_button {
    width: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #40d250;
    border: 1px solid #B89A67;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed,Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ch_hp_adjuster_input {
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #B89A67;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
}

.ch_hp_damage_button {
    width: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #9C2B1B;
    border: 1px solid #B89A67;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed,Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ch_hp_display {
    flex: 70%;
}

.ch_hp_numbers {
    display: flex;
}

.ch_hp_label {
    color: #58180D;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed,Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ch_hp_current {
    flex: 30%;
}

.ch_hp_number {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.ch_hp_sep {
    padding-top: 10px;
    flex: 10%;
    color: #58180D;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed,Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ch_hp_max {
    flex: 30%;
}
```

Sorry for posting so much code, but I don't know what is actually causing the issue here.

If you run the code and look in the top right corner, you will see the spacing issue I am talking about.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that there is also a little space above the first button - but you don't see it because there's nothing above it. There are a few ways to get rid of this little space above your buttons, but the quickest way would be to use `line-height: 0;`

Example:

```
.ch_hp_adjuster_button {
    line-height: 0;
    /* margin: 1px 0; */ /* Uncomment this if you still want a little spacing */
}
```